# Increase cloned Lion partition to larger hard drive

Tags: partitioning, osx-lion, macbook-pro, disk-cloning

After cloning a 250GB hard drive of a Lion install to a 1TB hard drive, I am unable to increase the size of the partition. Is there a way to force the OS to refresh the size of the hard drive? I believe that the OS still thinks it's on a 250GB hard drive. Thanks.

Comment: What software did you use to clone the drive?

Comment: I used a commercial grade hard drive cloner that did a bit for bit clone.

Comment: Why so coy about the name of the copying software?  It may be pertinent. A Lion installation is actually three partitions: an EFI partition, the OS partition, and a recovery partition.  Depending on what was copied, you might have these hidden partitions bracketing the original partition, preventing you from increasing the size of the OS partition.  Or, as you suspect, you might have copied the partition table verbatim which is giving the OS an incorrect size for the whole drive.  I don't know of anything to fix that problem except repartitioning the drive and restoring into the new partition.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be coy. What I meant to say is that I used a physical piece of hardware to clone my hard drive. Whatever software/firmware that comes on a Spartan SATA cloner is what I used.